# Keychain data can't be shared between apps

Tags: ios, cordova, keychain

I've got keychain dumper working fine on an iPad Air. I have a bunch
of apps where I am sharing keychain data. This works great. These apps
are older and compiled under Xcode 4. I've got a jailbroken iPad and have used Keychain Dumper which sees all these apps data.

I now have a new iOS App (Cordova HTML-based) which I use a different
keychain plugin for. It's compiled by xCode 6.

Keychain dumper (with -a) cannot see the data saved by this project,
even though it persists and restores correctly. Even when the app is
running, I cannot see the keychain data.  It also cannot share the
keychain data from the other apps even though I use the same bundle
seed etc, and follow the same recipe I always did.  It's writing in a
different location or something.

Have the defaults for saving keychain data changed somehow?

Comment: "which I use a different keychain plugin for" which one? and which one do you use in the other apps?

Comment: The original apps were Adobe Air, not cordova, so they used a plugin by Sticksports. I have gone so far as to transplant the sticksports library which actually writes the keys into the cordova plugin, and it still didn't work as expected. This is why I am now suspecting the compiler makes a difference. Diffferent default values for the security settings??? Just conjecturing at this point.

Comment: Are the plugins open sourced so we can take a look into the code? If so, provide the links to the plugins

Comment: Yes. The original plugin is here:  
https://github.com/StickSports/ANE-Keychain
The new plugin is here (my own fork to try to get things working): 
https://github.com/emulvihill/KeychainPlugin

And I am using the new library as so:
kc.setForKey(success, failure, keyname, keyname, Constants.KEYCHAIN_ACCESS_GROUP, keyvalue);

That is, I am setting the key and service to the same value (keyname) because that appears to be how the old sticksports plugin worked and I am attempting to maintain compatibility with data from the old apps.

Comment: Maybe is a silly question, but did you enabled the keychain sharing feature on your cordova app?

Comment: Actually that's not a silly question at all!  it reminded me that in my previous apps, there was an entry to add to the entitlements.plist. In Adobe Air, this is done with the following fragment: 

    <!-- A list of plist key/value pairs to be added to the application Entitlements.plist -->  
        <Entitlements>  
            <![CDATA[  
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
     <string>********</string>
    </array>
   ]]>
        </Entitlements>

I don't know what the equivalent process is for Cordova apps.  Is there some entry in the config.xml that can add entitlements?

Comment: The entitlements.plis is a xcode config file, you can do the same on a cordova app if you open the xcode project